# Scaling a text box

Tags: adobe-indesign

I want to be able to scale numerous text boxes (all with text threads) so that the scale includes the font size. I am using indesign CS (CC 2014)

Comment: Use the free transform tool.

Comment: Welcome to GraphicDesign! What have you tried? What tutorials have you looked at? What is going wrong with the approach you're using? You really should add more information about your situation, as it is this question is pretty unclear such that the answer seems very straightforward

Comment: Thank you Zach and Scott - both the free transform and the text box sizes at the top of screen allows me to re-size thee text box to 90% but the tread rolls over to the next page at the same size. I need the contents (type) to go down to 90% as well??

Comment: I'm sorry - I also can not work out how to post a screen shot!

Comment: Click the 'edit' link or click here: [edit]. Then use the image icon to upload a screenshot to imgur. It will automatically be posted in your question. Don't forget to commit the edit. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

Using the **Free Transform Tool** should allow you to scale text frames *and* their content.

[image]

[image]

Because it's text, **hyphenation, line breaks, and line lengths may cause a bit of reflow**. This is just the nature of text and frames.

Comment: Thank you Scott - this is exactly what I want it to do but the body font is remaining at 12pt when I need it to scale down to 10.8pt (there are headings and different font styles so I simply can't just select all the type and change the font size. I don't know if there is an error with the document or if I have checked a box which is not allowing me to scale the content??? file:///Users/jasminewilliams/Desktop/Screen%20Shot%202015-02-20%20at%2012.03.47%20pm.png

Comment: file:///Users/jasminewilliams/Desktop/Screen%20Shot%202015-02-20%20at%2012.04.04%20pm.png

Comment: Hi Scott, it seems there was an error or corruption with the document - if I copy and paste the text boxes to a new document they scale perfectly?!? It will take a little while to fix all 160 pages - but at least I can now make the print deadline. Thanks again for your help

Answer (score 0):

Jasmine, I had the same problem but managed to figure it out: go to preferences > general > Object editing > When Scaling > check the "Apply to content" box. There ya go :)

Comment: Please add a screenshot showing the commands you mention ...That makes your answer better understandable.